# Accessing legend entries exceeds matrix dimensions

Tags: matlab, legend

I am trying to plot some data with Matlab R2015a and as the data sets are changing for different plots I want to create the legend (semi-)automatically. I do this with a list of strings (called list) and then

```
leg = legend(list);
legtxt=findobj(leg,'type','text');
set(legtxt(1),'color','r');
set(legtxt(2),'color','b');
```

a.s.o. according to the entries.

However, no matter what index I give in the 'set(legtxt(i))' part, Matlab always tells me 'Index exceeds matrix dimensions.' Same, if I create the the legend manually by not using 'legend(list)' but explicitly typing the legend entries. Does anyone know why this happens or how to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use additional outputs from the call to `legend`. Specifically, check out the 2nd output called `icons` in the [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend.html).

As for the error, the call to `findobj(...)` yields an empty vector, so matrix dimensions are indeed exceeded. Indeed (from the docs):

> Starting in R2014b, the legend function returns a legend object. In
>   previous releases it returns an axes object.

So maybe that's why you can't use `findobj` to fetch legend text...

Anyhow here is how to solve your problem. In this example I create 3 plots and change the color of the text of the 1st and 2nd entry inside the legend:

```
x = 1:10;
y1 = sin(x);
y2 = cos(x);
y3 = x;

plot(x,y1,'y*',x,y2,'g--',x,y3,'k')

list = {'y1';'y2';'y3'};

%// You want to play with icons and possibly plots.
[leg,icons,plots,str] = legend(list)

set(icons(1),'color','r','FontSize',12)
set(icons(2),'color','b','FontSize',12)
```

Output:

[image]

Of course you can use the `plots` output to change any property you want of the plots to make them fit with their legend entry.

Comment: Very awesome, thanks a lot! I suspected that it was a change in one of the newer releases but could not find it in the release notes ...